# Problems with time correction on Debian

Tags: debian, time, timezone

I am trying to correct the time on the Debian server. I selected my timezone in the

```
/usr/bin/tzselect
```

I select the correct continent and country, when the system asks me if the date is correct and I have to say Yes or No the time is displayed correctly, however after I confirm and check it with "date" the time does not change ie. is the same as before running timezone config.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The system does not assume that everyone using it is in the same time zone the system is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way is use:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

also you can set this manually by copy one file with timezone settings:

> sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime

just change "Europe/Warsaw" to correct values ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Usually, I use the following to reconfigure my timezone:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

For more information, you can have a look at [this page](http://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges).

If your timezone is correct and you need to adjust your system clock, it is recommended to install and run ntp daemon. At least, you can use `ntpdate` command to update sync you clock.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to log out-and-in, or just change your TZ variable.